# Ansible: start or stop EC2 instance based on the current status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation, ansible

I have this playbook, which stop or start some EC2 instances currently filtered by the tag "Administrable" and works fine, but I need to add something and I'm a little lost here.

This is my playbook:

```
 - name: Obtener los detalles de las instancias
   hosts: localhost
   connection: local
   gather_facts: false
   tasks:

   - name: Obtiene los detalles de las instancias
     ec2_instance_facts:
      region: us-east-1
      filters:
       "tag:Administrable": OK
     register: datos
     tags:
       - always

   - name: Muestra los datos
     debug: msg="{{item.instance_id}}"
     tags:
      - datos
      - never
     with_items: "{{datos.instances}}"

   - name: Detiene las instancias
     ec2:
      instance_ids: "{{item.instance_id}}"
      region: us-east-1
      state: stopped
      wait: yes
     tags:
      - stop
      - never
     with_items: "{{datos.instances}}"

   - name: Inicia las instancias
     ec2:
      instance_ids: "{{item.instance_id}}"
      region: us-east-1
      state: running
      wait: yes
     tags:
      - start
      - never
     with_items: "{{datos.instances}}"
```

I want to do the same but only if the instance state is the opposite of the action, like: "Start the instances only if they are stopped and if they are currently running do nothing and finish" and "Stop the instances only if they are running and if they are currently stopped do nothing and finish".

I think this can be done with some filters, I already tried some options but none works.

Any clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html

I don't readily have anything ready that lets me test this, but I think something like the following might be okay:

```
  tasks:
    - name: figure out if shit's alive, yo
      ansible.builtin.command: echo taco
      register: alive
```

...

```
    - name: some normal task
      when: alive is not "taco"
```

You could also rely on the ansible facts not being able to retrieve the proper server data.. so something maybe like:

```
    - name: some other totally normal task
      when: ansible_facts['os_family'] is not defined # or empty? i dunno
```